# how to call wordpress function on click in a custom plugin

Tags: php, wordpress

I've been having a go at creating a custom plugin (simplified code below).

I have my plugin file (counter.php) which has 2 function in it called

```
displayCount() {
// output count and a link to add 1
echo '<a href="XXX">Add One</a>';
```

}
AND

```
addOne() {
$count = $count + 1;
```

}

My question is what to I replace XXX with or how do I call addOne function from my post page?

Comment: Hey there Ali! Please let me know if you need more information. If you find that you no longer need an answer to this specific question, please consider choosing an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You're attempting to modify the PHP on the user's end, but unfortunately all PHP has already run when the user is able to click the link. PHP is a server side language, Javascript is a client-side language. In order to pass data back and forth, you'll need Ajax.

However, it looks like what you're trying to do could be done with pure Javascript. Something like this:

```
<div id="counter"></div>
<a href="#" class="counter-add">Add one</a>

<!-- INCLUDE JQUERY HERE (or elsewhere on page, perhaps head) -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    // Create global JS var to track the count.
    var counter = 0;

    // On document ready we need to assign a click event.
    // We use document ready to be sure that we select all
    // initial elements when the page is loaded.
    jQuery('document').ready(function()
    {
        // On counter-add click...
        jQuery('.counter-add').click(function()
        {
            // Increment counter
            counter++;

            // Output counter value
            jQuery('#counter').text(counter);
        });
    });
</script>
```

**[Here is a working JSBIN copy.](http://jsbin.com/naracibira/1/edit?html,js,output)**